# Any Examples of URDF/MoveIt for Parallel Robots?

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on providing MoveIt support for a parallel (Delta-style) robot.  Are there any examples of current parallel-mechanism robots that are being used with ROS?

I have seen discussions from [2011](http://answers.ros.org/question/9050/using-ros-for-a-delta-robot/)  and [2013](http://answers.ros.org/question/112016/stuart-platform/), but no links to actual code.

I understand that we'll need to "cheat" a little in representing the robot in URDF, and provide our own FK/IK routines.  I think I've got a good handle on the required steps, but it would be helpful to review any other example implementations, if available.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217516/any-examples-of-urdf/moveit-for-parallel-robots?/) by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4976 on 2015-09-11

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-11**:
Are you intending to do the low level control of the delta with ros as well? Or just plan in Cartesian space for the eef?

**Comment by [danish-answers](https://answers.ros.org/users/29112/danish-answers/) on 2017-01-19**:
Hi,
do you have any updates on this?

**Comment by [danish-answers](https://answers.ros.org/users/29112/danish-answers/) on 2017-01-19**:
great, I have been looking into the ragnar. Can you give me a hint what was the hack you made? i understand that URDF does not support parallel robot.

**Comment by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) on 2017-01-19**:
The URDF is created with all floating joints. The tool plate is defined relative to base_link (a hack). The robot publishes 4 driven joint positions. A custom state_publisher node performs kinematics to compute the positions of all 8 links and the tool plate, and publishes the resulting transform

**Comment by [danish-answers](https://answers.ros.org/users/29112/danish-answers/) on 2017-01-20**:
thank you very much. tat was helpful

**Comment by [danish-answers](https://answers.ros.org/users/29112/danish-answers/) on 2017-01-20**:
I have a further question. Is MoveIt Integration available for Ragnar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We've actually completed this work, and [published](http://rosindustrial.org/news/2015/12/12/ragnar) the [ROS package](https://github.com/Blueworkforce/ROSRagnarEDU) for the delta-style [Ragnar](http://blueworkforce.com/ragnar/) robot back in December 2015.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2017-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipa-hsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26721/ipa-hsd/) on 2022-10-19**:
The package has been deleted / is not accessible anymore. Any reason?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-10-19**:
Comments under questions of 5 years ago with accepted answers don't have great visibility.

re: any reason: you'd have to ask Blue Workforce.

There are some forks of the package available though, see [Jmeyer1292/ROSRagnarEDU/network/members](https://github.com/Jmeyer1292/ROSRagnarEDU/network/members) fi.

**Comment by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) on 2022-10-19**:
For what it's worth: Blue Workforce, the manufacturers of the Ragnar robot and owner of its driver repository declared bankrupcy and `[were acquired by OnRobot](https://www.therobotreport.com/onrobot-acquires-blue-workforce-assets-robotics-developers/)` in 2019.  So perhaps you'd have more luck reaching out to OnRobot about this repository.